# Use Case for Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

We are building an web application to allow customers insight into their activity based on events currently streaming into ElasticSearch. A customer is an organisation sending messages to people.

A concern has been raised that a requirement to host this data for three years infers a very large amount of storage and high cost of implementation given Elasticsearch.

An alternative is to process each day's data into a report CSV stored in S3 and use something like Amazon Athena to perform the queries. Is Athena something that our application can send ad-hoc queries to in response to a web browser request? It is unlikely to generate a large volume of requests all the time, but I'm uncertain what the latency could be like.

Answer (score 0):

Athena is serverless. You can quickly query your data without having to set up and manage any servers or data warehouses. Just point to your data in Amazon S3, define the schema, and start querying using the built-in query editor.

Amazon Athena automatically executes queries in parallel, so most results come back within seconds/mins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Athena would be a possible solution to this use case – and done right it could also be fairly cheap.

Athena is not a low latency query engine, but for reporting purposes it's usually good enough. There's no way to say for sure without knowing more, but done right we're talking low single digit seconds.

You can approach this in different ways, either you do as you say and generate a CSV every day, store these for as long as you need, and run queries against them as needed. From your description it sounds like these CSVs would already be aggregates, and I assume they would be significantly less than a megabyte per customer per day. If you partition by customer and month you should be able to run queries for arbitrary time periods in seconds.

Another approach would be to store all your data on S3 and run queries on the full data set. As you stream data into ElasticSearch, stream it to S3 too. Depending on how you do that you probably need some ETL in the form of Lambda functions that partitions the data per customer and time (day or month depending on the volume). You can then run Athena queries on the full historical data set. The downside would be slower queries (double digit seconds for most queries, but I don't know your data volumes), but the upside would be full flexibility on what you can query.

With more details about the particulars of the use case I could help you with the details.